# Make the New Answers to Old Questions real time

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

The 10k privileges has a great additional advantage of looking at [New Answers to Old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions).

However, the updates are not real time like the other pages on Stack Overflow. Additionally, there is no ability to flag an answer directly from the tool: you have to go to the post and flag it from there.

I am sure many others would have faced a similar problem of pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> again and again and ending up destroying it.

Feature-requests:

- Make the "New Answers to Old questions" real-time. Example:
  [image]
- Add an ability to flag answers directly in the tool.

Comment: Often times, new answers to old questions are just facts to add on to the previous answer, which should be comments. Maybe have this feature only work if the old question has no answers...

Comment: Why is viewing new answers to old questions such an exclusive privilege? [I asked a question about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312296/why-is-seeing-updates-of-new-answers-to-old-questions-an-exclusive-privilege).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I agree, this would be a great feature. It might also be a good idea for Stack Overflow given the amount of <kbd>F5</kbd>'ing that I can imagine is being done.

<sup><sub>(really I just wanted to bump this feature request)</sub></sup>

Comment: I hope you're laughing right now if you're reading this on the New Answers To Old Questions page on meta.

Comment: hahaha too funny, or they'll be reading this in future time.

Comment: @TinyGiant, go and start scripting some so you can tag the question status-complete

Comment: There is a StackApp that does this ATM, http://stackapps.com/q/7049/42239